# Counting the number of distinct s-t cuts in a oriented graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, network-flow

I am trying to find the number of distinct s-t cuts in a oriented unweighed graph. In an article [Enumeration in Graphs](http://www.cs.uu.nl/research/techreps/repo/CS-1987/1987-07.pdf) p. 45 I found good way how to enumerate those cuts (section 7.3). Is there a faster or simpler algorithm I can use if I am interested only in the number of such cuts and I do not actually need to enumerate it?

The definition of a s-t cut I am using is following. We have a directed graph where two vertices are labelled **S** and **T**. Cut is a *minimal* set of edges of a graph such that by removing those edges there will no longer exist a path from vertex **S** to vertex **T**.

Comment: It's better to ask this in CStheory.StackExchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSteory.StackExchange was the place! My question was [answered there](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9399/counting-the-number-of-distinct-s-t-cuts-in-a-oriented-graph), in the **negative**.